# Unable to hide bootstrap fields using '.' selector

Tags: bootstrap-4, show-hide

I need to hide multiple fields based on user interaction with a decision modal window.  I have been unable to completely hide the fields effectively.

Ive tried to use a generic div class to show/hide the fields with that id.  This doesnt seem to work at all.  I have also tried by identifying each of the fields.  This hides the fields but leaves the labels.

Example of the bootstrap html.

```
                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-12" id="reviewSR_IPDiv">
                                        <label class="col-form-label" for="evnt-service-type">Service Type:</label>
                                        <label class="col-form-label ml-1" data-controller-id="evnt-service-type" data-value=""></label>
                                        <select class="form-control form-control-sm is-invalid js-control" required id="evnt-service-type"></select>
                                    </div>
```

I would like to use the '.' selector to just show/hide all of the divs.

```
$('.reviewSR_IPDiv').addClass('d-none');
```

Using the individual fields works, but the labels still show.  I want the labels to hide as well.

```
$("#evnt-service-type").addClass('d-none');
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code. Very small error. Here you use ID: 
`<div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-12" id="reviewSR_IPDiv">` 
and here you call a class `$('.reviewSR_IPDiv').addClass('d-none');`

Either add class `reviewSR_IPDiv` to the container or change jquery to `$('#reviewSR_IPDiv').addClass('d-none');`